# Windows 8 App - Creating and sending XML to a remote server within an App

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlite, windows-runtime, xml-serialization

I have a Windows 8 App that uses a SQLite database and I'm trying to backup an entire table on a remote server (SQLServer, but not Windows Azure).  What are the best practices for accomplishing this?

Ideally, I was thinking that I could create an XML stream in the App and post to a page that I created that would parse the XML and then insert the rows into our SQLServer db...but it seems that all of the examples of XML for Windows 8 only deal with *receiving* XML...not creating and posting XML.

(a) is there a better way to accomplish this?

(b) if not, is there a good example of an XML post that you can point me to?

(c) I can do JSON as well if that's an alternative.

Comment: this sounds more like a sync than a backup (for backup, just copy the file).  I haven't looked at this but the [Sync Toolkit for Windows 8](https://syncwinrt.codeplex.com) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Syncing is better practice rather than backup. I would recommend to read this blog post.

[Synchronizing WinRT/SQLite Using Sync Framework Toolkit](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/synchronizing-winrtsqlite-using-sync-framework-toolkit/) (With sample app)